# Getting colour from database to DIV background

Tags: asp.net, html, colors

I am retrieving a color code from a table stored in a database.

How would I be able to set the background color of a `div` based on that color code?

Comment: This is a very low quality question. Did you actually search on the internet for setting a value via the code behind?

Comment: Maybe you should read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by Javascript.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('DivName')[0].style.backgroundColor = "Your Color;
```

or by JQuery

```
$('#element').css('background-color','');
```

You will need to pull values from DB onto page and find its value and assign it

Comment: I thing OP is also asking how to pull the data from the DB and set it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean. If you mean on server side, or client with JS, if you mean just setting the background or also getting the color from database. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you save it in DB:

- 6 character string (HEX code) easy to read and write
- As integer (using 3 bytes for encoding the RGB amounts between 0 and 255), more difficult to encode and decode
- As byte array, with RGB amounts more easily encodeable and decodeable
- Many other ways..

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
<div id="div_Name" runat="server"></div>
```

in code behind

```
string color=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["color"].ToString();//your color string
div_Name.Style.Add("background-color", color);
```

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information on what you're trying to achieve and **how** you're trying to achieve it. Details!

---

It depends on how/when you want to fill the `div`. If you want the `div` to be filled when the page loads, the simplest way would be using PHP:

```
<div id="somediv" style="background-color:<?php
    // some database queries that output to $outputcolour
    $outputcolour = "#FF0000"; // this colour retrieved from database
    echo $outputcolour;
?>"></div>
```

If you're not sure how to connect to a database using PHP, see [this tutorial](http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/connect_mysql_database.php). You would need to **query** the database using the **WHERE** clause to get the colour value that you want, then echo the returned value (as shown in the script above).

---

If you want the `div` to be filled when a user clicks a button or something similar, you could consider using [AJAX](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ajax+introduction+-w3schools&oq=ajax+introduction+-w3schools&aqs=chrome..69i57.6164j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=813b0b1587a62d92&q=use+ajax+with+php+-w3schools&safe=strict) instead, or having the PHP echo that value to a specific class in your CSS file then using JavaScript or jQuery to add that class when ready.